# how to change variable value in callback function of getUserMedia in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using angular 2 for my application. I have used getUserMedia to access webcam. If webcam is available then success function is called and if webcam is not available then fail function is called. check function below.

```
var n = <any>navigator;
n.getUserMedia  = n.getUserMedia || n.webkitGetUserMedia || n.mozGetUserMedia || n.msGetUserMedia;
n.getUserMedia({video: true, audio:true}, this.onSuccess, this.onFail);
```

I have one variable `isCamera : boolean` defined .

```
export class CameraComponent implements OnInit {    
   public isCamera: boolean;
   ...
}
```

I have set this variable to true in `onSuccess` function and false in `onFail` function. But this is giving error. I am not able to set the value in callback onSuccess and onFail function. my code for these two function is

```
public onSuccess(){
  this.isCamera = true;
}

public onFail(){
  this.isCamera = false;
}
```

Can anyone tell how to assign `true` value to `isCamera` function in `onSuccess` function ?
I am getting this error :- 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'isCamera' of undefined

Comment: what is the actual error?

Comment: @mvermand Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'isCamera' of undefined

Comment: Can you show the file where the isCamera variable and the onSucces function are defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things here, you should really use getUserMedia from the mediaDevices interface, directly on navigator is deprecated (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

The reason why you can't set it is because in the callbacks, 'this' isn't what you think it is. So either use arrow functions in your callback or bind the callbacks to 'this'.

Arrow functions:

```
n.getUserMedia({video: true, audio:true}, () => this.isCamera = true, () => this.camera = false);
```

Binding:

```
n.getUserMedia({video: true, audio:true}, this.onSuccess.bind(this), this.onFail.bind(this));
```

Comment: I have used binding method and it works. Thanks mate

Comment: Cool. Please mark my answer as correct so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Tried the arrow function and it worked. You are a genius. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Callback function do not let you to use typescript's `this` scope
the workaround is here

```
n.getUserMedia({video: true, audio:true}, 
    function(){ // success
        n.isCamera = true;
    } , 
    function(){ //fail
        n.isCamera = false;
    }
);
```